# Compilation error using TCP on Arch Linux Arm

Tags: c++, linux, archlinux

Running Arch Linux Arm on my Beagleboad xM I'm trying to set up a web server to listen for commands, however whenever I try to compile a program that requires "netinet/in.h" it outputs the following errors:

```
netTest.cpp:(.text+0x14c): undefined reference to `__cxa_end_cleanup'
/tmp/ccaJk7mW.o:(.ARM.extab+0x0): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
```

Am I missing something? Can you compile on ARM?
Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: That's a linker error, not a compiler error. You're not linking things correctly.

Comment: Have any idea how I can fix this?  I can't find anyone having the same issue.  I'm somewhat new to this still.

Comment: Don't build (compile/link) with `gcc`, use `g++` instead. It will automatically link with the correct libraries for the C++ runtime.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize there was a difference. That did the trick.